# Edit Image in Photoshop

Tags: .net, photoshop

I need to send an image from my application, edit it in Photoshop and return it back.

My application should wait until the Photoshop Document is closed.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this..

```
MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();

myProcess.Start("photoshop.exe", "C:\\myImages\\image.jpg");

while (!myProcess.HasExited) {
// Do nothing while waiting.. Sleep for a few seconds might be a good idea
}

// Will be executed when process is closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("pathtoshotoshop.exe", "someimage.jpg").WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file name, you can check the date stamp until it's after the edit starts. You should also check the file attributes and make sure the file is not still open by PhotoShop.

You can use a timer to check every few seconds, instead of checking constantly which would slow down the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(path, "image.psd"));
```